# RichEditBox crashes while selecting text in Windows 10 1703 Creators Update (NULL_POINTER_READ)

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, richeditbox

**My app that uses RichEditBox crashes on devices with Creators Update. Users report that it happens while selecting text.**

The app is built for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. It works well in other versions of Windows 10. And the problem does not seem to be related to something in the app itself, but looks like a bug in Windows that started only in the Creators Update.

I have tested this app on my Mircosoft Lumia 550 and **sometimes** I experience **crashes while selecting text**. And **sometimes I stop seeing my custom popup-menu for the selected text**. 
My app uses RichEditBox to select and highlight text. When I select some text, a special popup should appear that will allow me to choose a color for highlighting. This popup-menu appears for some time without problem, and then it simply stops appearing. No matter how many times I try, it simply won't be shown again until I reload the document or restart the app. In other RichEditBoxes on the same page, this popup-menu still appears without problem.

However, personally I do not often use this app on my tablet/PC. Usually I use my Lumia. I can't say if it crashes often or not, but my users mostly complain about constant crashes while selecting text on their tablets.

In my Developer Dashboard in 'app crashes' section I can see some **exceptions that only happen in Creators Update**. Here are some of those related to the issue:

```
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTextBoxView::AreGrippersVisible  (v 10.0.15063 and later Insider builds - 10.0.16232, 10.0.16226, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!TextBoxBase_Internal::TxSendMessageHelper (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_clr.dll!ComCallWrapper::GetMethodTableOfObjectRef (v 10.0.15063, 10.0.16232, 10.0.16199, PCs only)
FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION_c000041d_msftedit.dll!CTxtEdit::TxSendMessage (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTextBoxBase::IsFrozen (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTextBoxView::GetSelectionEdgeRects (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTextBoxBase::OnIsReadOnlyChanged (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!TextServicesHost::TimerWindowProc (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_msftedit.dll!CTxtEdit::TxSendMessage (v 10.0.15063, only 1 occurrence on a phone of model "ATT-US-RM-1073_1004")
NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_msftedit.dll!CTxtRange::CharFormatSetter (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_c0000005_msftedit.dll!CUndoStack::PushAntiEvent (v 10.0.15063, PCs only)
```

Is there any way to avoid/workaround this bug?

I submitted [this bug here in FeedbackHub app](https://aka.ms/U9ufbi).

Comment: According to your description, it seemed that you would show a popup control when you selected text in RichEditBox. I want to know how you achieve it by coding. Because I cannot reproduce it in my side if I just put a RichEditBox on xaml page. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, what if this problem occurs only from time to time? I cannot simply do some actions and reproduce it on my side, so I even if I try to make an example, how do I know if it produces the exception or not? It would take me forever to do so. But you can play with the app in the Store (https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj9w0). When you use the Rich text mode, this happens from time to time. On some devices, as my users report, it happens more often.

Comment: I suggested that you could find a 15063 machine to debug your source code. To locate where the issue is.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, I already use 3 devices on 15063.413 (that is Creators Update), but the bug is quite rare. And even if I encounter the bug with the debugger attached, it simply will crash the app. The exception does not even come from my code, so I will not be able to fix it anyway, will I?

Comment: @Artemious you just contradicted yourself where you say >RichEditBox constantly crashes on devices with Creators Update.

Comment: @karann-MSFT, I'm sorry for the confusion. Actually, it does NOT happen all the time on devices that I use. It is rare. But some users report that it happens quite often - like 10 times during their reading and editing (during an hour or so). I tried to reproduce the issue on my side with the debugger attached, but the bug never happened.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, this application is the only reason why many people continue to use Windows-based device or prefer buying it. This app is only available on Windows, so if the users stop using this app because of this bug, they will simply buy Android or iPhone and have no reason to remain on Windows. So please, make sure to undo the changes made to RichEditBox in Creators Update, or fix this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I experience the same issue in a WPF application using the UWP's RichEditBox via XamlIslands.

Comment: @AttilaSzász I don't remember, but see if you can fix it by updating the UWP target SDK version